# Dynamic Properties on Model with EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, properties, model

Below is a basic ember model:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  birthday:  DS.attr('date'),
  day1: DS.attr('string'),
  day2: DS.attr('string'),
  day3: DS.attr('string')
});
```

For the purpose of this example, what if I had days go up to 50?  Rather than going line by line... day4, day5, day6... is there a way to loop through dynamically?   My first instinct is to use a MIXIN, and push these onto the object, but I don't think it would work if I had computed property:

```
isHoliday: function(){
    if(this.get('day1') == 'off'){
        return true;
    }
}.property('day1'),
```

Given that 'this' is in there and we have a return, I don't believe you can simply 'push' this onto the model to generate something like this:

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    birthday:  DS.attr('date'),
    day1: DS.attr('string'),
    day2: DS.attr('string'),
    day3: DS.attr('string'),
    isHoliday: function(){
        if(this.get('day1') == 'off'){
            return true;
        }
    }.property('day1')
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is strange approach but still possible:

```
var defaults = {
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    birthday:  DS.attr('date'),
    isHoliday: function(){
        if(this.get('day1') == 'off'){
            return true;
        }
    }.property('day1')
}

var dayProps = {};
var count = 20;
while(count--){
  dayProps['day' + (count + 1)] = DS.attr('string');
}

App.Person = DS.Model.extend(Ember.merge(defaults, dayProps));
```

instead defining with dynamic props, it is better to define `Day` model and have one-to-many relations with `Person`:

```
 App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  days: DS.hasMany('day') 
 });

 App.Day = DS.Model.extend({
  person: DS.belongsTo('person') 
 });
```

Comment: this seems to work, but what I can't wrap my head around is if I had the 'isHoliday' in the while loop.  Since there is 'this.get()' and 'return true'... it would process in the while loop not in the model?

Comment: if you had computed property for each property created in while loop, it would still work, you are just passing information about properties which will be processed inside DS.Model

Comment: If you are looking to add properties after your model has already been declared, you can get the model using `store.modelFor()` and then add properties using `model.reopen()`.

Comment: I think there's some miscommunication or I'm not getting it. If in your while loop, you put this:  dayProps['day' + (count + 1)] =  function(){
        if(this.get('day' + count) == 'off'){
            return true;
        } 
    }.property('day' + count); .... I do not think it'll work, because this.get() doesn't return in the loop, that part needs to 'execute' later ... no?

Comment: yes because you asked `can't wrap my head around is if I had the 'isHoliday' in the while loop` I put it there to show that you can add it

Comment: I'm saying imagine if there are multiple isHoliday 'object's you want to create through a loop... this:  dayProps['day' + (count + 1)] = DS.attr('string');  works just fine in a loop because there are no IF statements or returns.  If you have IF statements or returns inside of a loop, they execute in the loop, not later.

Comment: if you are solving real problem the whole approach is wrong, there no real cases were you would need to create property dynamically looks strange

Comment: it would be better if you describe me what are you trying to build then it would be easier

Comment: fair enough... essentionally given that ember 2 doesn't support view select for dropdowns... I'm trying to figure out a way to determine a checked/selected value for the option.  If I have a list of 30 items, the only way I assumed is to make this "isCityNyc": function(){ if( arrSearch('nyc',(this.get('cities') || '')) ){ return true;};}.property('cities'), for each city...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100001/discussion-between-matt-and-bek).